# Telerik RadGrid getDataItems() not working when paging is enabled

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid

I am trying to delete all rows on telerik radgrid  from the client-side. I can get this delete function to work but only when paging is disabled, otherwise when paging is enabled it just deletes the first page every time.

Is there a way that I can get this to work or there is a different approach?

Here is my callback when a button to delete all rows is pressed:

```
function DeleteDialogCallBack(args) {
            if (args === true) {
                var ajaxManager = $find("<%= MasterUserListRadAjaxManager.ClientID %>");
                var grid = $find("<%= UserMasterListRadGrid.ClientID %>");
                var masterTable = grid.get_masterTableView();
                var selectedRows = masterTable.get_selectedItems();

                var param = "Delete";

                for (var i = 0; i < selectedRows.length; i++) {
                    var row = selectedRows[i];
                    param += "|" + masterTable.getCellByColumnUniqueName(row, "ID").innerHTML;
                }

                ajaxManager.ajaxRequest(param);
            }
        }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete rows from a paged grid, you must use server side code

Because, the idea of paging is to load a predefined amount of data from server and render it to the client.

So, if your grid page size is 10 for example and you have 50 records in your database, the server just sends 10 records to the client at a time

So, your client code will not see the rest of your data that still on the server.
While server side code can delete from the data source itself

Comment: @user3614070, glad my answer could help you. Could you please vote up the answer by clicking on the up arrow to its left. Thanks in advance

Comment: mGouda thank you for your answer it did help me however I do not have enough reputation yet to vote up otherwise I will do it. Thank you!

Comment: @user3614070, Glad to know I could help, regarding voting up, never mind, accepting the answer is enough :)